# Sum and difference formula with decimals - Trig

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Can someone please walk me through the steps on how I can get an answer for a decimal problem involving sum and difference formulas?

Thank you very much,
Jeremy

If $\text{cos}(\alpha) = 0.167$ and $\text{sin}(\beta) = 0.529$  with both angles’ terminal rays in Quadrant-$I$, find the values of 
 $$\sin(\alpha+\beta)  \ \  \text{and}\   \cos(\alpha-\beta)$$
Your answers should be accurate to $4$ decimal places.

Comment: In the context of the problem, do you have trig tables?

Comment: Use your trigonometric identities, they may help.

Comment: The OP said: "without a calculator". My guess is trig tables are allowed, so just find the angles by reverse lookup, add them, and look up the trig values for the sum of the angles.

Comment: Why don't you walk us through the steps you know, and let's see where you get stuck. Do you know the sum and difference formulas?

Comment: @quasi we must memorize basic identities and unit circle but we are given the formulas for sum and difference

Comment: Without a calculator, it's a mess. You need to calculate square roots.

Comment: @GerryMyerson hello. My steps for this problem was to first split it into two triangles. One that contains cos(alpha) and another that contains sin(B). I find what is missing from both triangles such as sin(alpha) and cos(B). Once I have these values I constructed a sum and difference formula. (CosAlpha)(CosB) + (SinASinB) I then completed the problem by plugging in values and solving.

Comment: $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, so if you know either the $\sin$ or $\cos$ of an acute angle, you can find the other one.

Comment: @quasi That method still involves square roots, doesn't it? It will be a tough question to solve without a calculator.

Comment: @quasi, of course you are correct, but OP says he's meant to give answers correct to four decimals, and without a calculator. Using your formula, he'll have to evaluate some square roots.

Comment: The question can be answered without requiring hand-computation of square roots.

Comment: @XanderHenderson How? That's the question we're all asking.

Comment: Are you familiar with the angle addition formulae?

Comment: @XanderHenderson You mean this? $\sin(α + β) = \sin(α) \cos(β) + \cos(α) \sin(β)$

Comment: @XanderHenderson Cos(A-B) = (CosACosB) + (SinASinB) and Sin(A+B) =

Comment: The very nature of the statement of the problem strongly suggests that either calculators _are_ allowed, or else trig tables are available.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, I am attempting to use that formula to solve this problem.

Comment: Instead of looking to me for approval, perhaps you might try applying those formula?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Finding $\sin(α)$ and $\cos(β)$ still requires square roots and/or a calculator.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I have applied these formulas but keep getting the answer incorrect.

Comment: @quasi calculators are not allowed on the test but more simple variations of this question appear on the test that do not require calculators and can be done by hand.

Comment: Oi... I misread the problem---I thought all of the sines and cosines were given.  Ooops

Comment: @Jeremy Hernandez: If calculators are not allowed, then presumably trig tables will be provided. If so, see one of my earlier comments.

Comment: @Jeremy Hernandez: You mentioned simple variations. Ones which can easily be done by hand. For test purposes, those are the ones you have to worry about. For the problem you posed here, you need a calculator or trig tables, or else it's unfair.

Comment: @quasi can you please show me the steps I would use with a calculator. Questions on the test appear as "Find exact value sin(285)" or cot(pi/2 - x) those problems can be done by hand on the test. There are no tables provided because the values we are given are simple values that can be seen on the unit circle

Comment: @Jeremy Hernandez: You can do it. You have the sum formula and the difference formula. What you're missing are the values for $\sin(\alpha)$ and $\cos(\beta)$. But for any angle, you have $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, so as I mentioned in a previous comment, for an acute angle $x$, if you know either $\sin(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, you can find the other (with a calculator, of course).

Comment: @quasi I do not know how i would use that identity if sin(alpha) and cos(beta) are not squared

Comment: @Jeremy Hernadez: Square the one that's given, subtract from 1, then compute the square root (all with a calculator)

Comment: @quasi so by using one of the Pythagorean identities pretty much I can take the known sin(alpha)  value and find sqrt(1 - cos^2). After i have that i can put it back it into the equation of sum and difference

Comment: @Jeremy Hernadez: For the problem that you posed, you should edit out the "no calculator" phrase, and show your work, assuming it _is_ a calculator problem (and it surely _is_ one). If instead, you need help for variations that can be done by hand in exact symbolic form, ask a new question with one of those kinds of questions (and show your attempt).

Comment: @Jeremy Hernadez: Yes, for this problem, use the Pythagorean identities to find the missing trig values needed for the sum and difference formulas.

Comment: Note that your input data only has three decimal places.  The problem setter has an out by saying his numbers are exact, but then the data should have some trailing zeros to indicate that if you are asked for numbers to four places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then, if you have a calculator, then this becomes relatively simple. I'm sure quasi has already answered the question in the comments, but I'd just like to properly answer it. Three trigonometric identities will be particularly useful in this question.

> $\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)\equiv1$
>
> $\sin(α + β) \equiv \sin(α) \cos(β) + \cos(α) \sin(β)$
>
> $\cos(α – β) \equiv \cos(α) \cos(β) + \sin(α) \sin(β)$

Given $\sin(β) = 0.529$ and $\cos(α)=0.167$. I assume we are working in *radians*.

Find $\sin(α)$:

\begin{align}
\sin^2(\theta) + \cos^2(\theta) & \equiv 1 \\
\sin^2(α) + \cos^2(α) &= 1 \\
\sin^2(α) + 0.027889 &= 1 \\
\sin^2(α) &= 1 - 0.027889 \\
\sin^2(α) &= 0.972111 \\
\sin(α) & = 0.98596 \space(\text{to 5 d.p., reject} \sin(α) \lt 0)
\end{align}

Similarly, we find that $\cos(β) = 0.84862.$

Then we plug those values into the identity.

\begin{align}
\sin(α + β) & \equiv \sin(α) \cos(β) + \cos(α) \sin(β) \\
\sin(α + β) & = 0.98596 \cdot 0.84862 + 0.167 \cdot 0.529 \\
& = 0.9250 \space(\text{to 4 d.p.})
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\cos(α \space – β) & \equiv \cos(α) \cos(β) + \sin(α) \sin(β) \\
\cos(α \space – β) & = 0.167 \cdot 0.84862 + 0.98596 \cdot 0.529 \\
& = 0.6633 \space(\text{to 4 d.p.})
\end{align}

Comment: As the input was only three decimal places it needs justification that your values are accurate to four.  Since the actual values are close to $1$, that may be true but I am doubtful about the cosine being that good.  That said, this is clearly the intended approach.

Comment: @RossMillikan I agree, this isn't the best question for an exam/test. But with exact values, it would be easier, as the OP has stated.